# When to use "the" before plural nouns?

Tags: definite-article, plural-forms

When are we allowed to use the definite article "the" before plural nouns? Is it true that when we talk generally, we don't use "the" before plural nouns, for example:

> **Americans** like to swim in the ocean.

> Reading **books** is the best way to increase your knowledge of the world.

Comment: General statements require no article: Apples are good for you. But: The apples on the table look great.

Comment: The second sentence is incorrect. The verb should agree with the gerund (reading, which is singular). Compare: "Reading a book is the best way...", "Reading the books we were assigned is the best way..."

Comment: @Laurel I fixed some problems in the post, including the agreement issue.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan My understanding is that on ELL in particular it is strongly disfavored for others to make grammar corrections on questions, because such errors may illuminate the (mis)understandings and skill-level of the OP. Instead one may offer corrections in a comment or an answer.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Thanks for pointing that out. Do you know if it's written anywhere officially, or has it been mentioned in comments etc.?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan
See https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2770/91457 https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5252/91457 https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2465/when-should-i-correct-an-ells-grammar https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4866/91457 https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5607/rejecting-edits-that-do-not-improve-question-a-question-of-degree https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4572/appeal-of-edit-rejection https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4836/91457 https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3460/91457 Note that not all agree.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Thanks for the references. I'm always careful when I edit posts, but I'll keep this point more in mind now.

Answer (score 1):

A definite article may be used with a plural noun if, in context, some specific set of things is being described.

- > Americans like to swim in the ocean. [image: Green check mark, indicting correct form] [*"Ocean" is a singular form, and "the ocean" is idiomatic for ocean waters in general.*]
- > Reading books is the best way to increase your knowledge of the world. [image: Green check mark, indicting correct form] [*"the best way" indicates a specific preferred method; "books" is a plural form meaning all books or books in general, so no article is needed or wanted.*]
- > I studied the development of the romance languages [image: Green check mark, indicting correct form] [*"the romance languages" is a specific set of languages, so a definite article is needed.*]
- > I am eager to study the languages in school. [image: red X indicating an incorrect form] [*"languages" refers to languages in general, so a definite article is not proper.*]
- > Jane won almost all the races.  [image: Green check mark, indicting correct form] [*"the races" refers to a particular set of races, held on a specific occasion which should be identified in coin text.*]
- > Ford makes the automobiles. [image: red X indicating an incorrect form] [*"automobiles" does not seem to indicate any specific group here, so a definite article is improper.*]

Answer (score 0):

There are only two articles in English: **the** and **a** (or **an**). **The** is a definite article and is generally used to refer to a specific noun. **A** is an indefinite article and is generally used to modify a specific noun. When the noun is not specific, you don't use an article. For example:

> Americans like to swim in the ocean. (general)
>
> The American likes to swim in the ocean. The Brit doesn't. (specific)

> Reading books is the best way to increase your knowledge. (general, although I would strike the word "books" and just say "Reading")
>
> Reading the text book is the best way to pass the class. (specific)
>
> Reading a text book is the best way to pass a class. (specific)

Based on the context, whether something is general or specific is not always clear. In fact, the presence or absence of an article might convey critical meaning. For example:

> I saw lions at the zoo today. (implies that at some point during the day, I cast my eyes for at least a second on some lions).
>
> I saw the lions at the zoo today. (implies that I went to the lion exhibit).

Whether you use **a** or **an** is a [separate to
pic of its own](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/how-do-you-know-whether-to-use-a-or-an#:%7E:text=A%20and%20an%20are%20two,begins%20with%20a%20vowel%20sound.). Suffice it to say that it depends on the **sound** of the word the article precedes.

If only it were this easy! Unfortunately, when you refer to or modify a noun that represents a geographic place, you have to memorize when you do and when you don't use an article. And it quickly gets very confusing.

Instead of [listing out the rules](https://www.monmouth.edu/resources-for-writers/documents/articles.pdf/), I'm going to give an example that illustrates how confusing the rules are.

> When you refer to a lake, bay, mountain, continent, island or street by its name, you don't use an article (note that rivers are not included). For example: Lake Hartwell; Narraganset Bay; Mount Reiner; and the Mississippi River.

> When you refer to a *group* of lakes, mountains or islands, you **do** use an article. For example: the Great Lakes; the Blue Ridge Mountains; the U.S. Virgin Islands.