# If this question is grammatically correct?

Tags: articles, singular-vs-plural

> Some CO2 moves from **the roots** of plants to microbes in the soil

May I ask if this question is grammatically correct? I thought "the" didn't come with a plural noun **(rootS)**. If that sentence is true, what would be the case "the+N**s**".

Comment: "If this question is grammatically correct?" is not grammatically correct.  Also, it's quite normal and common to use "the" with plural nouns.  Also, I don't understand the last sentence in this question.  I therefore don't understand what you're asking or why you're asking it.  Can you explain why you think "the" shouldn't be used with a plural noun?

Comment: Your sentence isn't a question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where you got the idea that *the* cannot be used with a plural.

Perhaps you are thinking of *a(n)*. The "indefinite article" *a(n)* cannot be used with a plural noun. But *the* can be used with singulars,

> the root

plurals,

> the roots

and mass nouns,

> the quality of the material.

The question of **when** it is appropriate to use "the" and when it is not continues to be a challenge for English learners. In many cases it is straightforward (use it when the speaker can reasonably assume that the hearer knows which thing or things they are talking about), but not always.

Answer (score 1):

In English, "the" serves as the definite article for all grammatical genders and numbers. It does not change between singular and plural. See for instance [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The).

This is different from *indefinite* articles - "a" and "an" can *only* be used with singular nouns, and with a plural noun are normally replaced by *no article at all*. See for instance [this Grammarly article](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/articles-with-plural-nouns/), which gives this example:

> [Incorrect] I have a books in my locker.
>
> [Correct] I have books in my locker.
>
> [Correct] I have the books in my locker.

Note that the second and third sentences are both grammatically correct, with *different meanings* - "I have books..." is not making any specific claims about *what* books, and is equivalent to the singular "I have a book..."; whereas "I have the books..." refers to some specific books previously mentioned or relevant in context.

See also a previous question on this site, [When to use "the" before plural nouns?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/313884/9488)